# Cant Change GitAhead Password

Tags: github, credentials, gitahead

I have read through many solutions for the problem I have but nothing seems to work.  The HTTPS credentials window keeps popping up on git ahead.  After typing in my password, the window goes away briefly then pops back up (I'm assuming that means the password is incorrect).  I have three options in the credential manager for git:

```
GitHub - https://api.github.com/username,
git:https://github.com, and
git:https://username@github.com
```

I have changed all three passwords multiple times, so I know the password I am typing in is correct.  Is there another password that needs to be changed somewhere or some other step I need to take?

I am quite new to using gitahead, so I apologize if the answer is an obvious one.

Comment: You're working against github - which doesn't allow password authentication for git access. You have to get a Personal Access Token

Comment: I believe that GitHub only dropped support for accessing the API with basic authentication. It should still be possible to access git (e.g. push/pull) via HTTPS with username and password.

Comment: What platform are you using GitAhead on? Integration with credential managers is slightly different for each one.

Comment: Hi, fredrik was correct, I just needed to generate a personal access token.  Thank you all!